# NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined

Tags: python, ipython, caffe, pycaffe

I am working on Caffe framework and using PyCaffe interface. I am using a Python script obtained from converting the IPython Notebook **00-classification.ipynb** for testing the classification by a trained model for ImageNet. But any **get_ipython()** statement in the script is giving the following error:

```
$ python python/my_test_imagenet.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/my_test_imagenet.py", line 23, in <module>
    get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
```

In the script, I'm importing the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')

# Make sure that caffe is on the python path:
caffe_root = '/path/to/caffe/'
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')

import caffe

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 10)
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

import os

# ... Rest of the code...
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this error?

Comment: where have you imported this?

Comment: I have imported this in the python script where I'm trying to use the 'get_ipython()' statement.

Comment: In my case, I was deploying on Flask application hosted on Azure and no need for the ipython. I commented it.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You have to run your script with ipython:

```
$ ipython python/my_test_imagenet.py
```

Then `get_ipython` will be already in global context.

Note: Importing it via `from IPython import get_ipython` in ordinary shell `python` will not work as you really need `ipython` running.

Comment: I tried the above but it gives the following error: "UsageError: Invalid GUI request u'inline', valid ones are: pyglet, osx, qt5, qt, glut, gtk, gtk3, tk, wx".

Comment: @AdarshChauhan use 'matplotlib auto' instead of 'matplotlib inline'.

Comment: @beezz How can I test (inside a script) if my scipt has been launched by `ipython` instead of `python` ?

Comment: @SebMa you can catch ``NameError`` in plain python caused by ``get_ipython`` not present

Comment: This is coming from the output of `jupyter nbconvert`... why would it create a file that doesn't run? Seems to defeat the purpose of that command. Further, why is the output beginning with `#!/bin/env python` if it was really intended to be run with `ipython`?

Answer (score 24):

If your intention is to run converted .py file notebook then you should just comment out `get_ipython()` statements. The matlibplot output can't be shown inside console so you would have some work to do . Ideally, iPython shouldn't have generated these statements. You can use following to show plots:

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: is there a way to convert these statements?

Answer (score 11):

`get_ipython` is available only if the IPython module was imported that happens implicitly if you run ipython shell (or Jupyter notebook).

If not, the import will fail, but you can still import it explicitly with:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
```

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add that converting ipynb file to py having magic functions in your script trigger the same error as well since for instance `%%time` converts to `get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time')`

Why so? [Magic functions](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html?highlight=magics) (magics) are often present in the form of shell-like syntax, but they are python functions under the hood.

The conversion from cell magics to get_ipython() commands is a part of nbconvert and is required to get a runnable python script, as cell magics are not valid python outside of a notebook cell(things like magics or aliases are turned into function calls)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).