# Call IPython 5.x magic 'whos' from Python2 script

Tags: python, ipython, workspace

I want to show my ndarray variables "workspace" when there is an exception, so I did the following code :

```
import sys
import numpy as np
try :
    a1 = np.random.random_integers(5, size=(3,2))
    functionThatProvokesAnException(*arguments)
except Exception as why :
    print("=> ERROR: %s" % why,file=sys.stderr)
    from IPython import get_ipython
    ipython = get_ipython()
    ipython.magic("whos ndarray")
    sys.exit(-2)
```

But it says :
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'magic'`

Can you help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'get\_ipython' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538758/nameerror-name-get-ipython-is-not-defined)

Comment: @jordanm In other words, I guess it's IMPOSSIBLE to run it like this : `python myscript.py` to call ipython magics, am I understanding right ?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes

Comment: @jordanm Now, how can I test (inside my script) if my scipt has been launched by `ipython` instead of `python` ?