# Can I only use ipython through the jupyter notebook ?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do the following tutorial : [Tensorflow Object Detection API on Windows - error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247921/tensorflow-object-detection-api-on-windows-error-modulenotfounderror-no-modu)

I managed to do Step 9 whuch is running the programm with Jupyter but got stuck at step 10 "open the script in your chosen Python editor (ex. PyCharm) and run it". I have the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leahj\Documents\models-master\research\object_detection\object_detection_tutorial.py", line 40, in <module>
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined
```

which is probably coming from this line :

```
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

I have already downloaded the ipython module but from what I have undertand I can only use it through Jupyter ? Which makes no sense with the instruction of step 10. Any idea ?

By the way, I'm still very confused about why the jupyter notebook is better than the IDLE shell so if somebody could help me for that too ?

Comment: You can use IPython prompt without Jupyter, as shown in [NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538758/nameerror-name-get-ipython-is-not-defined)

Comment: I'm not sure, look at the answer to that post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538758/nameerror-name-get-ipython-is-not-defined What do you think ?

Comment: Notice that in both questions  `ipython`, not `python`, prompt is used: "Note: Importing it via `from IPython import get_ipython` in ordinary shell `python` will *not* work as you really need `ipython` running."

Answer (score -1):

type IPython it should work. 
hope it helps

Comment: where ? Not sure I understand your answer, sry