# Trying to get a script to run which references Ipython, have installed, but doesn't work

Tags: python

I am new here. My question concerns trying to get a particular script to run, which is a script I got from someone else.

In the 5th line of the script they write the following:

```
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
```

I have tried running this script from powershell and get the following error:

```
name: get_ipython is not defined
```

According to Anaconda, I have ipython installed. I have tried running this script via the Anaconda Prompt, and it still will not run. I even tried importing ipython with an import command and still no luck.

Any ideas?

- Ankur

Comment: check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538758/nameerror-name-get-ipython-is-not-defined) hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you have to run your script with iPython

e.g.

```
$ ipython myscript.py
```